# REACT NATIVE How can I highlight an item with a scrollview and increment/decrement the highlighted item?

Tags: react-native, highlight

I am building an 'Initiative Tracker' for home use. My goal is to have the first item at the top of the list highlighted by default and use a counter that keeps track of the turns to highlight the item to correspong with its turn.
Eg. When the '+' button is pressed, the next item should be highlighted and the previous item should return to normal.
I am currently using the map function to display an array. I feel like there should be a way to use the index and a style to achieve what I want, but I've had no luck so far.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

related code below:

```
let Encounter1Array = [
  { name: "goblin1", init: 5 },
  { name: "goblin2", init: 8 },
  { name: "goblin3", init: 15 },
  { name: "goblin4", init: 3 },
  { name: "goblin5", init: 9 },
];

function InitiativeTrackerScreen() {
  const [encounter, setEncounter] = useState(Encounter1Array);
  encounter.sort(function (x, y) {
    return y.init - x.init;
  });
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.wrapper}>
      <ScrollView>
        {encounter.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.ItemDisplayContainer}>
                <View>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={{ fontStyle: "italic", fontSize: 16 }}>
                      {item.name}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>
                      Initiative: {item.init}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I add "const [increment, setIncrement] = useState(1);" or something like that, I think I should be able to adjust that variable with an increment/decrement button but i'm not sure how to use that hook to change the style of the item in the array that corresponds with the increment of the turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need extra state to keep track of the index of the element you want to highlight. Then you can use a conditional statement to match to right index and switch its style.

```
const P = ({ list }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  return list.map((item, i) => 
    <View style={i === current ? highlightStyle : style}>
      <Button onPress={() => setCurrent(current + 1)}>
        {"+"}
      </Button>
      {item}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This was enough to go off of. I don't have the rep to upvote yet or I would!